# One call to decorator function suppressing the other one

Tags: python, python-decorators

From the following code

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.is_logged_in = False


def is_authenticated_decorator(function):
    print('Decorator called')

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        user = args[0]
        if user.is_logged_in:
            function(user)

    return wrapper


@is_authenticated_decorator
def create_blog_post(user):
    print(f"This is {user.name}'s new blog post")


user_1 = User('John')
create_blog_post(user_1)  # 1

user_1.is_logged_in = True
create_blog_post(user_1)  # 2
```

I expected the output as

```
Decorator called
Decorator called
This is John's new blog post
```

Instead, I am getting the output as

```
Decorator called
This is John's new blog post
```

When I comment out the statement marked as #2, I am getting the following output

```
Decorator called
```

Why is this output getting suppressed in the presence of #2?

Comment: You only call `is_authenticated_decorator` once: when you define `create_blog_post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_authenticated_decorator` is only called once when the function is given to the decorator. It's `wrapper` that's called multiple times. To see each time the function is called, the `print` should be in the `wrapper` that's eventually bound to the name `create_blog_post`.